# Why the DNS service is consuming so much mobile data?

Tags: iphone, network, dns, data

I have reset the mobile data statistic the day before. So these are data incurred within a 24 hour window.

[image]

I don't understand why the DNS service will consume a disproportionate amount of data. Understanding it may help me to understand some irregularity of my mobile data usage (namely 100 MB on a Sunday morning was used even though I was indoor using Wi-Fi throughout)